# Fetch an input field into android from php web server

Tags: php, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a form that has an input field that captures firstname written in html processed by php using MySQL to send data to user table. 
Is there a way I can fetch that field into android app, after fetch android creates that firstname input field automatically into SQLite, when user is done capturing data that input is destroyed at session end. I know it’s possible in Java, can it be done in php?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your php script in every 1 min or you can set a timer in android. It will call that script and check whether if there is a newly added field. Then update Android application. But it is kind of not a good practice.

You can use firebase for this kind of behaviour. Use the firebase real-time database. If you update any field in that db using web application. It will be automatically triggered android application and update it quickly. Follow thess links https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ , https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/ .It will help for u.

You don't need to fully change your db to firebase for applying this. You can update firebase db with only that field when you enter that value using web application. Then u need to keep only that kind of field there.